# Error in deploying wso2am on openshift: zip END header not found

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am deploying wso2am on openshift using helm chart on an air gapped environment and I am getting the following error during the cp pod initialization.
Link to chart: https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/advanced/am-pattern-4/README.md
here are the logs from openshift:
Start WSO2 Carbon Server
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /opt/java/openjdk
CARBON_HOME environment varable is set to /home/wso2carbon/wso2am-4.0.0
Using Java memory options: Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
INFO {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Initializing configuration with deployment configurations
SEVERE {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer perform} - Error occured while deploying bundles in the dropins direcotry
java.util.zip.ZipExceptions: zip END header not found
...
my kubernetes version is v1.21.1+6438632

I have tried to transport the image again to the air gapped environment with the thought that maybe the first time it was corrupted, but still the same result.
Also, the image in docker desktop in the air gapped environment DOES work fine so the problem is probably not corruption.

Does anyone know why it happens?